# Add item to class conditionally

Tags: php

I only want to add the `setTestEventCode` part of this snippet when a condition is met:

```
$request = ( new \FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\EventRequest( $pixel_id ) )
->setTestEventCode( $fb_pixel_test_event_code )
->setEvents( $events );
```

```
if( $fb_pixel_test_event_code && !empty( $fb_pixel_test_event_code ) ) {
    // Add ->setTestEventCode( $fb_pixel_test_event_code ) to \FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\EventRequest
}
```

How do you attach an additional item to a class method? (if that's the correct terminology).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
$request = new \FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\EventRequest( $pixel_id );
$request->setEvents( $events );

if( $fb_pixel_test_event_code && !empty( $fb_pixel_test_event_code ) ) {
    $request->setTestEventCode( $fb_pixel_test_event_code );
}
```